# Restart IIS website from MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I'm looking for a way to restart the current running website (from the admin page)
from an MVC controller, with C#.NET

Why i need it?
i have a bug in a website but it only happens after the website runs a random amount of time which makes it really hard to find,
meanwhile i still need a remote way to restart the site from my phone quickly if needed.

Comment: You DO realize that if it were hosted in the same app that this would restart everything, including the admin page?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes but i need it for somthing

Comment: didnt try anything yet

Comment: Is your MVC app running under administrator context? Typically IIS apps run with underprivileged user credentials. You'd need to use WMI, but in any event I don't see doing this without seriously compromising security of the application / entire IIS server.

Comment: i would add something like a powershell that runs, and its only if user is admin as im not worried

Comment: Restarting IIS is a nasty brute force way to solve your problem. Can't you just restart the app pool instead?

Comment: i can try, how can i do this within controller? by the way i wrote 'IIS website' note the whole IIS

Comment: I'd start with `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` perhaps (that should recycle the app, not the app pool), then move on if that doesn't help. But, you really need to figure out what bug is causing the app to break and fix that.

Comment: for sure! il figure it out. i put logs and more it just can take sometimes a month till it happens, so i need to have a backup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ASP.NET application could restart because really a lot of reasons. It
>   probably happens more often than you think. ASP.NET web application
>   will restart because of:
>
> - Change in Web.Config file. Change of any parameter, adding of space character or even changing file's modified date will cause app
>     restart.
> - Change in machine.config, just like for web.config.
> - Change in /bin folder. Application will restart if you add, update or delete any file in /bin folder.
> - Change in App_Code folder. Adding, deleting or editing classes inside App_Code will cause application restart.
> - Change in Global.asax file, like in web.config.
> - Change in App_LocalResources folder
> - Change in App_GlobalResources folder
> - Change in App_WebReferences folder
> - Change in Profile configuration
> - Reached compilation limit, defined with numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart in machine.config file. Default value is 15. ASP.NET watches for any changes in files. When certain number (15 by default) of files is changed, web application is restarted
>     automatically. The reason for this is to save memory on server. On
>     some websites where files are generated dynamically, this could cause
>     frequent restarts.
> - Antivirus software changes file's modified date. Antivirus program scans files like Web.config or Global.asax. Some antivirus programs
>     change Modified date of these files and that cause pretty frequent
>     restarts, which decrease website performances.
> - IIS restarts, and all websites will restart too.
> - Change of physical path to web application
> - IIS recycled website due to inactivity (20 minutes by default). If website has no visitors, IIS will unload it from memory to save
>     resources. Application will be started again on when next visitor
>     comes.

Here's what I would normally do to restart the application.

1. Call `UnloadAppDomain` from the code, although full trust permission is required to do so.

   `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()`
2. Deliberately change the gloabl.asax or web.config file modified date attribute

   `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(MapPath("~/global.asax"), DateTime.UtcNow);`
   `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(MapPath("~/web.config"), DateTime.UtcNow);`

Answer (score 7):

A very easy solution which i used to use whenever i want to logout all users from an application is by creating / deleting (if exists) a dummy .dll file from inside the bin folder.

you can name this dll file whatever you want but by creating / deleting it will restart the whole application (pool) and fix your problem..

The beauty about this solution is that you don't need a special permissions for your web application.

Comment: i love that! that's called thinking out of the box

Comment: this dummy.dll should be what? can i put a blank file ending .dll?

Comment: exactly just create any file (text file) with .dll extension lets say dum.dll ...  
if the dum.dll exists then delete it ... :)

Comment: @CMS yes... empty file ending with .dll

Answer (score 3):

Create a .bat file name `IISresart.bat`

and In it i write

```
iisreset
```

iisreset stops and then start IIS.

And ASP.net i write

```
            string str_Path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\IISresart.bat";
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str_Path);
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process batchProcess = new Process();
            batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
            batchProcess.Start();
```

And it restarts IIS.

Note.I tested it on asp.net web form .I should work on MVC also.
And for no windows add this line **processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;**

Comment: thanks il try it, but i would also try the other options in the comments could be it will be better for me,

Comment: if using NET CORE https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

Another option is killing the w3wp process. I didn't need any extra permissions for my controller to run the following:

```
var powershellCommand = @"get-process w3wp | stop-process";
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell")
{
    Arguments = $"/c {powershellCommand}",
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

var p = Process.Start(procInfo);
```